# Why in CoordinatorLayout doesn't work layout constraints

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

In my android application I use CoordinatorLayout,with AppBarLayout,CollapsingToolbarLayout 
But some functional don't work. 
In CardView i can't move TextViews with app:layout_constraint  "Start, Top, End and Bottom"

[With click we can see my UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyUZt.png)

```
       <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
               xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    tools:context=".activities.DetailActivity"
                    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
                <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
                        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="150dp"
                        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

                    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                            android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
                            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
                            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
                            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/Ar-Rahman">
                        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                android:layout_height="attr/actionBarSize"
                                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
                </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
                <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                        android:id="@+id/fab"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_margin="16dp"
                        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
                        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end"/>

                <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

                    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                  android:id="@+id/arabic_name"
                                  android:text="Arabic_name"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                         app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                             app:layout_constraintEnd_toTopof="translate"/>
                        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                  android:text="@string/example_transate"
                                  android:id="@+id/translate"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
                </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
            </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

I want to in CardView 1st textView below second TextView

Comment: views inside cardview are direct child of cardview and not constraint layout. So any constraints you have applied will not work. you need to take constraint layout inside cardview

Answer (score 0):

To set constraints of View in `CardView` you have to take `ConstraintLayout` in the CardView and have to put all Views inside that `ConstraintLayout`. Then only constraints will be set.

**You can't set constraints to direct child of CardView. Constraint properties only applicable to direct child of `ConstraintLayout`**

Try below code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context=".activities.DetailActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/main.appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_collapsing"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/Ar-Rahman"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        app:layout_anchor="@id/main.appbar"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|end" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/arabic_name"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Arabic_name"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/translate"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/example_transate"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/arabic_name" />
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```